# Unstable fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When considering the system

\begin{cases}
x' = (A-By)x \\
y' = (C-Dx)y, & 
\end{cases}

($A,B,C,D > 0$)

I am trying to understand how to tell that the fixed points $(0,0)$ and $(C/D,A/B)$ are unstable. If I'm not mistaken, Lyapunov functions can be used to show that a point is stable but not that it is unstable. I was thinking of finding the eigenvalues (if we consider the system as $\bf{x'} = Ax$), but the eigenvalues will involve $x$ and $y$ and that hasn't happened before as I've been solving exercises, so I'm not sure if that is the way to go...

Comment: Incidentally, there are Lyapunov functions (sort of) that can be used to prove that an equilibrium is unstable; see, e.g., [Chetaev function](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chetaev_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues will stop involving $x, y$ after we evaluate the linearization at the fixed points.  Here is how.

Let's compute the linearization of the right-hand side:
$$
L(x,y) = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
A - By & -Bx\\
Dy & C - Dx\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Evaluating it at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, we get:
$$
L(0,0) = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
A & 0\\
0 & C\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
so the eigenvalues are $A, C$.  Since they each have a positive real part (I know, you said they are real and positive, but I am using language suitable for a more general setting), the fixed point $(x, y) = (0,0)$ is unstable.

Similarly inspect the eigenvalues of $L(C/D, A/B)$.